# Storing Load test results in Database using Controller and Agents

Tags: sql-server, load-testing

I have a load test solution with one load test and one web test. I have created a Agent where the load test solution lies and a Controller which has a SQL server set up. So i am using the Controller to store the Load test results in database. While running the test case i am facing the below issue -

**The load test results database could not be opened. Check that the load test results database specified by the connect string for your test controller (or local machine) specifies a database that contains the load test schema and that is currently available. For more information, see the Visual Studio help topic 'About the Load Test Results Store'. The connection error was: An error occurred while attempting to create the load test results repository schema: To create the database 'LoadTest2010' your user account must have the either the SQL Server 'sysadmin' role or both the 'serveradmin' and 'dbcreator' roles**

Note - The same solution runs fine for two of my colleagues. So i think it is something to do with permissions. I have matched the permissions which i and my colleague share on controller, agent, database, they are exactly the same.

I am blocked from two days, it would be great if anyone can spend some time and help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can anyone please have a look

Comment: The connection string for the `LoadTest2010` database is locally stored in Visual Studio 2010. Perhaps you have not use correct credentials or you haven't defined it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Load Test Repository is configured at Controller Level. So, if someone else can do Load Tests, configuration is ok.

Maybe, you are not using a remote Test Controller in your Test (Local Testing only).
You should create a remote test settings in VS and specify the remote test controller.

[image]